# Telegram API POST /editmessagereplymarkup method executes with delay

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

**Given:**

- Telegram channel
- Telegram group
- Telegram bot with long polling strategy on board which handles all updates
- Messages with reply markup buttons
- Bot is based on https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots

**Action:**

Click any button twice (or more) in short period of time (1-2 seconds)

**Problem:**

When I click buttons in group - everything is ok, but when I click same buttons with same logic in channel:

The first api call executes very fast
But the second api call needs about 5 seconds to get responded, which freezes business logic and gets user annoyed

Methods:

```
private fun updateChatMarkup(messageId: Int, votes: Map<VoteValue, Int>) =
  EditMessageReplyMarkup()
      .setChatId(chatId)
      .setMessageId(messageId)
      .setReplyMarkup(createMarkup(votes)).let { execute(it) }   

private fun updateChannelMarkup(messageId: Int, votes: Map<VoteValue, Int>) =
  EditMessageReplyMarkup()
      .setChatId(channelId)
      .setMessageId(messageId)
      .setReplyMarkup(createMarkup(votes, messageId)).let { execute(it) }
```

Comment: Maybe share some code to help you better?

Comment: updated with code

Comment: As far as I know, telegram blocks multiple button clicks from a single client in a short period of time...

Comment: @Pato05 thanks for reply, but is there any documentation about that?
And also why do multiple clicks work well in chat but not in channel?

Comment: @imbananko are you using reply keyboards or inline keyboards? The problem is when you are an admin of that channel or subscriber?

Comment: @imbananko do you send answerCallbackQuery after first button click?

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#my-bot-is-hitting-limits-how-do-i-avoid-this the limitations do not really cover this, imo.

Comment: @wowkin2 hi, I'm using replyMarkup keyboard. 
Both admins and users face the same problem. 
Right now I'm using answerCallbackQuery after each button processed, but the problem existed long before I started using answerCallbackQuery

Comment: @imbananko but you need to send answerCallbackQuery at the beginning of your handler, not after button processed. You can see that in most documentation examples.

Comment: @wowkin2 hi sorry for long reply. I made a little investigation, but the point is - there is no correlation between how fast I do answerCallbackQuery and how fast telegram updates my inline buttons on the channel. I experimented making answerCallbackQuery at the beginning of update handle method - results are always the same: first update - lightning fast, second and next - 5-seconds delay. Please correct me if I'm wrong